# How to prevent do.call() from printing all data frame entries for class "call" in a model?

Tags: r, random-forest

If I use `do.call()` to run a model with parameters supplied as a list, the "call" returned with the model lists all entries within any data frames of the parameters. This prints an extremely long model output for large datasets.

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
do.call(randomForest, list(Species ~ ., data=iris))
#Call:
# randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1,  4.9, 4.7,
#4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8,...
```

Is it possible to prevent printing the data frame entries so the output matches a normal model call, for example, to randomForest?

```
randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
#Call:
# randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

I could try to reconstruct and replace the "call" slot in the model object after assigning it, or set it to `NULL`, but this seems like a bad solution.

```
mod <- do.call(randomForest, list(Species ~ ., data=iris))
mod$call <- 'randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)'
mod
#Call:
# "randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)"
```

I'm sure there is a better and simpler solution, but I cannot find it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `quote` :

```
do.call("randomForest", list(Species ~ ., data = quote(iris)))
```

giving:

```
Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.67%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          4        46        0.08
```

Answer (score 1):

`substitute` also [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75512192/r-do-call-function-returns-to-much/75512429#75512429):

```
do.call("lm", list(Species ~ ., data=substitute(iris)))

Call:
lm(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
     1.18650      -0.11191      -0.04008       0.22865       0.60925
```

Comment: Thank you for linking that other issue - that's great. I searched around and could not anything on it.